# Search for a file in folders and sub folders using file name if found copy to another folder in vba macros

Tags: excel, vba

Search for a file in folders and sub folders using file name if found copy to another folder in vba macros
The code shows no error but the file is not copying from the folder, i need to loop through sub folders and find a file.

```
Sub copy_files_from_subfolders()    
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim fsofile As Object
    Dim fsofol As Object

    sourcepath = "FINAL CUT\"
    destinationpath = "Desa\MECA\"

    If Right(sourcepath, 1) <> "\" Then
    sourcepath = sourcepath & "\"
    End If

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(sourcepath)
    If fso.FolderExists(fld) Then
        For Each fsofol In fso.GetFolder(sourcepath).SubFolders
            For Each fsofile In fsofol.Files
                If Right(fsofile, 6) = 566978 Then
                fsofile.Copy destinationpath
            End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do all of the folders in the destination path exist?

Comment: Sorry you are asking for destination path, only one folder is in destination path

Comment: Are you sure the name of the file you want to check ends with the *number* 566978 ?

Comment: there are about many files in the folders and subfolders, I need to find some pdf files starts with the numbers of 6 digit, followed by _PTA, eg 123456_PTA.pdf,123456_AOP.pdf,123456_HUD27011.pdf, i need specifiacaly these there files, but the number may vary every search. but the name after number is that i mentioned above, that the reason i searched by the number.

Comment: there are about many files but i need only 3 files starts with the number of 6 digit, eg 123456_PTA.pdf,123456_AOP.pdf,123456_HUD27011.pdf but there are many files with this number but i need only theses there files to copied in destination folder. thankyou for the help

Comment: If there are many files with the number in their file name, then what's the naming rule for the three files you want? Are they the only ones with an underscore after the number?

Comment: Yes there are many files in the same number in different subfolders, among them i only need files eg 123456_PTA.pdf,123456_AOP.pdf,123456_HUD27011.pdf, should be copied to destination folder

Comment: these files don't have same name as they will vary with the name followed by the number

Answer (score 1):

You're searching for the number using the Right-function, but this fails to take into account the file-extension that follows it. You could try something like (assuming the extension is the same):

```
Right(fsofile, 10) = "566978.txt" ''change extension to whatever
```

If the file-extensions aren't of the same length, you could determine the position of the dot in the name and use the Mid-function.

Alternatively, you could just check if the numbers you're looking for occur within the filename using, instead of the Right-function:

```
If InStr(1, fsofile, "566978") <> 0 then
```

This should only cause issues if there are files with longer strings of numbers, because for example you could have a file named "123556978123.pdf", which would be a false positive.

Comment: there are about many files in the folders and subfolders, I need to find some pdf files starts with the numbers of 6 digit, followed by _PTA, eg 123456_PTA.pdf,123456_AOP.pdf,123456_HUD27011.pdf, i need specifiacaly these there files, but the number may vary every search. but the name after number is that i mentioned above, that the reason i searched by the number

Comment: am searching for pdf files with numbers

Comment: @DESA If there's always max 6 digits in the name of files you're looking through, you can problably use: 
 If InStr(1, fsofile, "566978") <> -1 Then

Comment: @DESA I edited my original answer to include the InStr option. Have a look.

Comment: I edited the line but it copies all the file available in the subfolders to destination

Comment: there are about many files but i need only 3 files starts with the number of 6 digit, eg 123456_PTA.pdf,123456_AOP.pdf,123456_HUD27011.pdf but there are many files with this number but i need only theses there files to copied in destination folder. thankyou for the help

Comment: @DESA Well with the instr-function you could also place the entire name "123456_PTA.pdf" or anywhere in between. How specific you want to be is up to you depending on the probability of false positives.

Comment: Yes i mentioned like that the problem is this code copied all available files in the destination path, it not checking for the name

Comment: @DESA My bad; The value to compare should be 0 instead of -1. That's why it's not checking properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer i found
  Sub copy_files_from_subfolders()
        Dim fso As Object
        Dim fld As Object
        Dim fsofile As Object
        Dim fsofol As Object

```
    sourcepath = "FINAL CUT\"
    destinationpath = "Desa\MECA\"

    If Right(sourcepath, 1) <> "\" Then
    sourcepath = sourcepath & "\"
    End If

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(sourcepath)
    If fso.FolderExists(fld) Then
        For Each fsofol In fso.GetFolder(sourcepath).SubFolders
            For Each fsofile In fsofol.Files
                If InStr(1, fsofile.Name, 566978 & "_PTA") = 1 Then
            fsofile.Copy destinationpath
            End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But he problem is it is checking only on level of subfolders, can any one tell how to search in all the subfolders, i.e mainfolder->subfolder->subfolder like that.